# Material UI - XGrid: hiding multiple columns gives Error

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

As per the title, I was hiding couple of columns in xgrid and it throws a error/warning in the console.

> **Warning:**  Failed prop type: Material-UI: The `anchorEl` prop provided
> to the component is invalid. The anchor element should be part of the
> document layout. Make sure the element is present in the document or
> that it's not display none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug. XGrid issue log: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/1372